# Regex to match variations of I am: I'm, Im, Iam, I am

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that can match the various variations of the string I am. Particularly I am ( with `\s+` separating the two words ), I'm, Im, and Iam.

I tried to do it here, but it didn't seem to work: `I\s+?a?'?m` making the white-space, a, and ' optional.

How would I properly do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\bI'?\s*a?m\b
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/2

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put the `?` after `+` because it wont match your text if it doesn't contains space for example `Im`.Using `?` after `+` or `*` Is appropriate just when you want a non-greedy matching.

```
^I\s?a?'?m$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ueR9HfcdCmHrqcru)

Comment: `?` after `+` is perfectly valid; it just does lazy matching instead of greedy matching. In this case `\s+?` behaves exactly the same as `\s+`.

Comment: @AJRichardson Indeed and i just mean in this case!